# Error loading SharedPreferences on startup

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm obviously doing something wrong. On my splash screen, when it decides which activity to go to, I have the following code:

```
SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
                boolean disclamerChecked = getPrefs.getBoolean("disclamer", false);
                boolean medicalScreeningChecked = getPrefs.getBoolean("screening", false);
```

So, I'm trying to read 2 Boolean that should be false on app installation and 
when the setup is done it should be permanently true.

Now, in my Activities (Disclamer only at the moment) I have the following thing:

```
private void setDisclamerPropertie() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    startupPrefs= getSharedPreferences("startupPrefs", MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = startupPrefs.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("disclamer", true);
    editor.commit();
    return;
}
```

This function is called in On Create function, and when "accept" button is clicked it should save the Shared Preference (Or at least that is what I need to happen).

Button works, it goes to next activity and that one goes to next again, but when I reload the App, it seems that Boolean are not saved and app asks again for the confirmations.

So, where am I wrong, in writing preferences, or something is missing in reading correct preferences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reading from the default shared preferences, but writing to a named one ("startupPrefs"), so there are 2 separate instances of shared preferences

Comment: Ouch... True, I've changed load to read from "sturtupPrefs", and it is OK now. Tnx!

Answer (score 2):

You're using different preferences.

```
startupPrefs= getSharedPreferences("startupPrefs", MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
```

This should also be:

```
startupPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
```